# Exact meaning of equivalence in distribution

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability, random-variable, equivalence

Consider the real-valued random variables $X,Y,Z,W$ all defined on the same probability space.

Let $Y\equiv f(Z,W)$ for some measurable function $f$.

Suppose I am told that "$X$ is **equivalent in distribution** to $Y$".

Does this imply, among other things, that $X|Z$ is **equivalent in distribution** to $Y|Z$?

Does equivalence in distribution means equivalence  of all  joint, marginal, conditional probabilities?

---

As a practical example: suppose $\{Y, Z,W\}$ mutually independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, and $X$ takes value in $\{0,1\}$.

In what follows "$Be(p)$" denotes "Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$" and "$\sim$" denotes "distributed as".

Consider

(1) $X\sim f(Y, Z, W)$
for some Borel measurable function $f:[0,1]^3\rightarrow \{0,1\}$

and

(2) $X\sim 1\{W\leq t(Y, Z)\}$ for some Borel measurable function $f:[0,1]^2\rightarrow [0,1]$

(2) implies (1) by setting $f(Y,Z,W)\equiv 1\{W\leq t(Y, Z)\}$

**Does (1) implies (2)?**

---

My considerations:

(a) (1) **implies**  $X|Y, Z\sim Be(Pr(f(Y, Z, W)=1| Y, Z))$

(b) define $t(Y, Z)\equiv Pr(f(Y, Z, W)=1| Y, Z)$

(c) hence, $X|Y, Z \sim Be(t( Y, Z))$ which is an **implication** of (2)

How can I conclude that (1) implies (2)?

Comment: You haven't postulated anything that would even help us make sense of "$X|Z$".  To do so, you need to stipulate that $X$ and $Z$ have some joint distribution.  "Equivalent in distribution" means literally that: $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution function.  They needn't even be defined on the same probability space.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. I have added that the random variables are all defined on the same probability space. What can I say now? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't say any more than the definition includes, which I provided you in the first comment.